# Meteor JS: Page not scrollable after loading additional divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Unfortunately can't share source code/example as it is corporate, but have an issue with Meteor JS loading additional content.

For example, on this website: https://madewith.meteor.com/
you can click "Load More" and it loads additional `<div>s` , and voila! you can scroll down the page.

In my case, I would load a div, and **until I resize my browser window**, it won't redraw/let me scroll.

What gives..do you know?

Comment: have you tried using jquery `infinitescroll` ? http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: If you create a [mcve] as you should when posting questions here, you will not be divulging any corporate secrets.  Otherwise, the best you can hope for is speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your body tag in your css:

```
overflow-y: auto
```

See this post for more info:

[Webpage not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824821/webpage-not-scrolling)